# Python - CSV file writing to same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a register script in Python 3 using CSV files however when it imports the username and password to the CSV file it appears in the same line.
For example, if I make an account with the username and password as test and then make another one called test2 it adds it to the CSV file like this:

```
test, test, test2, test2
```

When I want it like this:

```
test, test
test2, test2
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
def register():
print ('Follow the register instructions')

username_check = False

while username_check == False:

    username = input('Please enter a Username: ')

    with open('users.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if username == row[0]:
                print ('Username not available, try again.')
                username_check = False
            else:
                username_check = True

if username_check == True:

    password_check = False

    while password_check == False:
        password = input('Please enter a Password: ')

        score = "0"

        account = username + ',' + password + ',' + score

        with open('users.csv', "a") as f:
            for row in account:
                f.write(row)

        print ("Thank You for Registering, You can now login")
        print ("")
        login()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't run due to at least one indentation error.  It requires manual input and other code unrelated to the question you're asking.

Comment: Full Code here: https://pastebin.com/mGkNVgXa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
account = username + ',' + password + ',' + score + '\n'

with open('users.csv', "a") as f:
    f.write(account)
```

'\n' means new line
'\t' means tab

Answer (score 1):

As account is a string (`username + "," + password + "," + score`) when you iterate `for row in account`, you are iterating a string, then each time, `row` is a character of string account. I guess you could get rid of the for loop, and simply `f.write(account + "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

You used the `csv` module to read the data, why not also use it to write the new data:

```
with open('users.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(account.split(','))
```

should result in each account entry as a new row in `users.csv`.